# Seeing blank display when running Shopizer application

Tags: h2, shopping-cart, shopizer

I have been able to successfully download, compile, and run Shopizer. Unfortunately, when I attempt to display the home page, I get a blank page. By "blank" I mean that there is nothing on the page, not even undisplayable  HTML!

I also attempt to log in as the admin. When I point my browser to the admin page (http://localhost:800/admin) I get the login page but when I enter the username and password (admin and password) the Shopizer throws an exception.

I am running this application in Eclipse, so was able to debug the code. I am finding that the exception from the admin login is caused by a failure of the application to read the username from the database. It attempts to get information from the database when you log in, but the query for information on the admin user returns null and that causes an exception to be thrown.

Apparently, it is getting nothing from the database. I am running this using the default H2 database configuration, and from what I have understood reading some of the information on their forum, the H2 database is run as an embedded database in this application. I also understand that on first running the database is initialized and test data is put in. I have also looked at the database file, it has data in it.

Yet for some reason, Shopizer fails to get user info about the admin user. I suspect that some of the other blank pages I am getting are caused at least partially by a failure to read product and other information, as well.

Does anyone know what is causing this failure to read the database? Has anyone else seen this behavior before? Is there something that needs to be done to enable access (Shopizer's documentation is somewhat incomplete so who knows what else might need to be done to make it work)? Or is there something that needs to be done to make it able to read the database?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the app from the command line first

```
cd shopizer
./mvnw clean install
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

When running from eclipse once you have imported shopizer root project make sure the H2 file resides under sm-shop

Have you tried to configure mysql ?

Yes the schema is created and updated during startup